# Cosa significa "sciamano" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nella introduzione al *Grammelot dell'avvocato inglese* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> Ma le piú terribili sono senz'altro quelle ragazze che escono la sera all'imbrunire... cala il sole... e loro, oplà!, evadono, **sciamano** per le strade. Questa è la piú grossa delle incoscienze perché la ragazza per bene, se deve sortire all'imbrunire, esce accompagnata dalla madre, dal padre, da un fratello e dal cognato armato mitra e bombe a mano!

Ho consultato parecchi dizionari e ho trovato il verbo "sciamannare" e il sostantivo "sciamano". Tuttavia, 
non mi sembra che questi abbiano a che vedere con il significato del verbo che appare nel testo. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "sciamano" nel passaggio precedente?

Comment: T'è sfuggito [“sciamare”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sciamare)?

Comment: @DaG: Effettivamente, mi è sfuggito "sciamare".

Comment: (Visto che se ne sta discutendo ampiamente in meta: *non* sono io che ho votato negativamente questa domanda.)

Comment: Grazie del chiarimento, @FedericoPoloni, ma io non ho mai pensato che tutti i voti negativi provengano da te e non pretendo saperne l'autore. In questo caso, però, posso immaginare la ragione del voto negativo: avrei dovuto cercare meglio nel dizionario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

È il presente indicativo del verbo [sciamare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sciamare/) alla terza persona plurale, nell’accezione 2 del vocabolario Treccani:

> **2.** estens. e fig. Di persone, partire, spostarsi in massa, o in gruppi, allontanandosi dalla propria casa, dal proprio paese o da altro luogo: *la diaspora costrinse intere popolazioni a sc. in diversi continenti; la vita dura del capo di famiglia, investito pro-tempore della proprietà del fondo avito, ha consentito agli altri figli di sc. nel mondo, di creare nuove famiglie* (Einaudi); con senso più generico, uscire o spostarsi in gran numero, prendendo direzioni diverse o anche una stessa direzione, con movimento per lo più vivace o agitato: *passavano in gruppo dei bambini che si rincorrevano sciamando verso la scuola* (Palazzeschi); *dopo la partita, la folla cominciò a sc. fuori dallo stadio*; anche di veicoli o altri mezzi di trasporto: *finito il raduno, le vetture sciamarono strombazzando per le vie; immense azzurrità adriatiche dove le vele arance sciamavano* (D’Annunzio).